# Getting an "application defined or object defined" error

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get all the empty cells to display `"***"`

```
Function test()
Dim rng As Range, cell_ As Range

Set rng = Range("D1,AL367")
For Each cell_ In rng
    If IsEmpty(cell_) Then
        Sheets("DailyMean Report").Range(cell_) = "***"
    End If
Next cell_


End Function
```

Comment: `Set rng = Range("D1:AL367")`

Comment: `cell_.Value = "***"`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to containing a typo in the range, your code isn't very efficient. There is no reason to loop cell by cell if you want to get the blank ones to display `***`. Instead, do it in one line of code:

```
Sub test()
    Range("D1:AL367").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = "***"
End Sub
```